# Defining a system generated ID for a mulch-values column

Tags: database, database-design

I have the following tables:-

[image]

Now as the IP address is a muli-valued attribute for a Technology table (for example a server can have multiple IPs), so I have created a new table named TechnologyIP . But should its primary key be TechnologyID + IP address . or I should avoid defining a non-system generated values as part of a primary key .

So should the PK for the technologyIP table  be a single ID column (as shown above), instead of being technologyID + IPaddress?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, both solutions will work well. In general, I find it easier to work with an autoincrement PK for every table so I would go for an extra single ID column.

Comment: Thanks for the reply; but i think this will break normalization, but improve performance ?

Comment: I don't think this particular case breaks normalization.

Comment: since the table will have two primary keys (TechnologyID+IPAddress) and the ID column?

Comment: No, only ID column is the PK. The other combined key is a candidate key but will not be used as such

Comment: @Pleun If there is a candidate key, you _have_ to enforce in the physical database, otherwise you risk data corruption.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: did I deny that? I just said it will not be used as a primary key. There can be only one PK, you know..

Comment: @Pleun Your wording was a bit off: you said _"is a candidate key but will not be used as such"_. Well, it will be used as a key. You didn't say "primary". And there can be multiple keys (one primary and multiple alternate), you know ;)

Comment: @JohnPeter The table will not have "two primary keys". In this particular case, it will have one primary key `{ID}` (that also happens to be surrogate) and one alternate key `{TechnologyID, IPAddress}` (that also happens to be natural and composite).

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd make the PK be technologyID & IPAddress. Primary keys are typically based on an underlying index. When you use a PK structured this way, you'll get great read performance pulling back all IPs for a specific piece of technology.

If you're going to add a lot of additional attributes to your TechnologyIP table, you MIT want a surrogate key, but in this case you have a natural key that should serve quite well.

Comment: why i want a surrogate key, if i want to add a lot of attributes??

Comment: When you're tracking a large number of attributes on an object, it may become better to treat each Technology <-> IP Address mapping as an object in its own right, rather than as a collection of IPs attached to a technology. much of that depends on your long term plans for the data.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll need the natural key `{TechnologyID, IPAddress}` **in any case**, to ensure the same IP address cannot be repeated multiple times for the same server. You cannot "remove" the existing natural key by creating a [surrogate key](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/surrogate-key/info) (such as the auto-incrementing ID column).

The choice is not about "natural vs. surrogate key", it is about "natural vs. natural + surrogate key".

Every constraint has a cost, so all things being equal the lone natural key will be cheaper. You should create a surrogate key only if you have a specific reason for it, such as:

- To make the FOREIGN KEYs in child tables slimmer.
- To avoid ON UPDATE CASCADE referential action.
- To "pacify" your object-relational mapping (ORM).

**--- EDIT ---**

It just occurred to me that you might *not* want to share the same IP among multiple servers. Is that the case? If so, then just the `{IPAddress}` should be the key, not the `{TechnologyID, IPAddress}`.

Comment: but in my case i want to avoid setting the primary key to a value that might change overtime. as in the future the server IP might change . so although the IP address can uniquely identify any record , but it is exposed to change. while the ID system generated key will stay the same all the time. so if inside my log i am tracking the changes of any server and i refer to its IP address , then this tracking information become invalid if the IP is changed, or it is assign to a different server ?? so what do u think ?

Comment: @JohnPeter This is what _"avoid ON UPDATE CASCADE referential action"_ point listed above is about. The log will reference the surrogate key, so it won't need to be updated when the natural key changes.

Comment: thanks for the reply; so my original approach of creating an ID surrogate key + creating a unique constraint on the IP field is the right approach to follow (as shown in my original picture)?